# Regex Replace single Char at FileName in a certain string

Tags: java, regex

I have following scenario:

```
File '/oname=$INSTDIR\workspace\jetty\work\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\sample\service\core\util\SomeModule$SomeModulesData$SomeModulesDataBuilder.class'     '${ADDEDSOURCE}workspace\jetty\work\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\sample\service\core\util\SomeModule$SomeModulesData$SomeModulesDataBuilder.class'    ; Added file
File '/oname=$INSTDIR\workspace\jetty\work\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\sample\service\core\util\CoolUtil.class'  '${ADDEDSOURCE}workspace\jetty\work\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\sample\service\core\util\CoolUtil.class'     ; Added file
```

I want to replace the '$' Sign in the name of *.class (could be other as well) with '$$'. I am able to get the filename, but just want the one group of Dollar sign.

Here is my example:
https://regex101.com/r/Wa2cF6/2

In java I do want to just do :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "File '/oname=$INSTDIR\\workspace\\jetty\\work\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\classes\\com\\sample\\service\\core\\util\\SomeModule$SomeModulesData$SomeModulesDataBuilder.class' \t'${ADDEDSOURCE}workspace\\jetty\\work\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\classes\\com\\sample\\service\\core\\util\\SomeModule$SomeModulesData$SomeModulesDataBuilder.class' \t; Added file";
    s = s.replace("\\\\([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)\\.\\w+'\\s", "$$");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

And expect a result of

```
File '/oname=$INSTDIR\workspace\jetty\work\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\sample\service\core\util\SomeModule$$SomeModulesData$$SomeModulesDataBuilder.class'   '${ADDEDSOURCE}workspace\jetty\work\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\sample\service\core\util\SomeModule$$SomeModulesData$$SomeModulesDataBuilder.class'  ; Added file
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Try `(\\(?=[^\s'"\\]+\.class['"])|\G(?!\A))([^'"$]*)\$`. See regex live demo here https://regex101.com/r/6G72rX/2 and [**Java code here.**](https://ideone.com/3dpZHi)

Comment: @revo Thank you it is doing what I need. Man is that complex, I thought it would be some more easy to read

Comment: @revo could you modify the regex so it is replacing just first occurrence of the .class file name? So the second .class name needs to be untouched if even available

Comment: See it here https://ideone.com/srksdA

Answer (score 0):

So you want to replace the `$` sign only in the class name? I would definitely go on a lower level using indexes and the `StringBuilder` class:

```
private static final String testString =  "File '/oname=$INSTDIR\\workspace\\jetty\\work\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\classes\\com\\sample\\service\\core\\util\\SomeModule$SomeModulesData$SomeModulesDataBuilder.class' \t'${ADDEDSOURCE}workspace\\jetty\\work\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\classes\\com\\sample\\service\\core\\util\\SomeModule$SomeModulesData$SomeModulesDataBuilder.class' \t; Added file";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(replaceDollars(testString));
}

private static final Pattern PATH = Pattern.compile("(\\'[\\S]*)(\\\\[\\w$]+\\.class\\')");

public static String replaceDollars(String string) {
    Matcher m = PATH.matcher(string);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int end = 0;

    while (m.find()) {
        builder
                .append(string, end, m.start())
                .append(m.group(1))
                .append(m.group(2).replace("$", "$$"));
        end = m.end();
    }

    builder.append(string, end, string.length());

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Using the following regex: `(\'[\S]*)(\\[\w$]+\.class\')` to find files in the input string.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will go with the comment answer, as it is less code and